# How to implement stake.com model of deposit & withdraw flow for my crypto poker casino?

Tags: transactions, bip32-hd-wallets, utxo, javascript, merchants

In stake.com for each user they generate separate bech32 address for deposit & displays the deposited amount as balance in top of the navigation bar.

Similarly for withdraw they just ask for the amount to be withdrawn & receiver address for withdrawal.

Currently for our setup we're generating bech32 address with publicKey & privateKey using node JS. But for sending transaction to another bech32 wallet it's more complicated to calculate transaction fee & sochain.io costs too much.

How to implement this model of deposit & withdraw model for my crypto poker casino?

[image: Deposit Flow in stake.com]

Comment: Are you asking how you can estimate the transaction size in advance, or how you can reduce your cost for facilitating a high payment volume on Bitcoin?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very broad and depends on a lot of circumstances.

The most straight-forward approach to any hot web wallet is building your solution on top of bitcoin-d and the existing JSON-RPC API. (https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/)

There are libraries for almost every language.(https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)#Languages)

- Run a dedicated server/VPS
- Install bitcoin-d at your preferred version
- Update bitcoin.conf if you want pruned, also you can set `walletnotify` here which works like a callback that will ping or run a script of your choosing whenever funds are received to the wallet.
- Familiarize yourself with the wallet JSON RPC calls (https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/#wallet-rpcs)

Implement into your site as necessary.